# In ASP.NET where and all we can refer the assembly reference?

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.NET where and all we can refer the assembly reference in Project? for ex: generally we can refer the file in `web.config` file as like below
[image: In ASP X page we can refer assembly like below]

`<%@ Register assembly="System.Web" namespace="System.JavaScript.Web" tagprefix="ex" %>`

Except this what are the other pages in which we can refer assembly as like above.

Answer (score 0):

secondly you can refer the assembly in project. Right click on references and select the required assembly, and click add. This will add assembly reference to your project. 
Some assemblies like ajaxtoolkit.dll or if you are using some partial views (ascx) pages, then you can use the reference which you have mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for response

Comment: I need to refer register assembly inside project ex. ASPx page or view page.

Comment: can you please tell which files possibility for use register assembly reference

Comment: hi jaya, It actually depends on for what purpose you need that assembly. If you want this assembly for designing purpose then you can add assembly as same as you have shown in question. but if you want assembly for code purpose in aspx.cs file, then you will have to add reference to your project only